# Log Unsub Event for Job and Not Unsubscribe from All Subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, unsubscribe

Right now we send to multiple brands in a single business unit. We also use data extensions for all sending.

I am looking to concept a way to log an unsubscribe event to a send job for reporting purposes and tracking, however I would like to unsubscribe the subscriber only from a brand and not the All Subscribers table. Considering the individual brand subscribers are all contained in data extensions I am wondering how this is possible where we don't use the list model. For instance, if I am signed up for emails from Nike and Jordan, I would like to only unsubscribe from Jordan and still receive emails from Nike.

Again, we do not use the list model, and use data extensions with a custom preference center. Ideally I would like this logic to also extend to a one-click unsubscribe page. I'm assuming a suppression list is possibly the way to achieve this? But I'm not sure if we could still use the LogUnsubEvent as well for tracking purposes in Email Tracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider All Subscribers to be a calculated / aggregated view, not a raw data table.

It calculates the "status" field based on, among other things*, *Logged Unsubscribe Events* which show up in the _Unsubscribe Data View**.

*Other things considered are, e.g. _Bounce Data View, think status = "held".

**(Depending on your Business Unit Setup, BU specific unsubs also surface in _BusinessUnitUnsubscribes Data View which is a tacked on solution to support "unsub from this BU only" configuration in some basic way. Without the latter, "status" was a mess to understand as n "status" values had to reflected in one All Subscribers List.)

This means:

You cannot log an unsub event that won't be registered by "the process that calculates what shows up in All Subscribers"- Logging an unsub event by definition equals to writing a record into the _Unsubscribe Data View.

This is literally what the term "logUnsubEvent" tries to convey:

Log = Write

UnsubEvent = record in _Unsubscribe Data View

And you cannot remove anything from the _Unsubscribe Data View once entered.

Of course, you DO WANT to logUnsubEvents for each unsub, or you produce other problems. (e.g. Einstein would not register your "custom" unsubscribe without LogUnsubEvent for scoring, your "custom" unsubscription would work different from the List Unsubscription, causing more confusion, etc...)

So you cannot prevent the behavior, but you can fix the symptoms:
What you can do, is to change (=reset to active) the All Subscribers Status post hoc in an automation.